# How to run multiple commands at once asynchronously in fish shell?

Tags: fish

In bash, I would run

`(npm install -g npm@latest && npm install -g neovim bash-language-server vscode-langservers-extracted graphql -language-service-cli solidity-language-server typescript-language-server)&` to install some packages I need.

I have been trying to do the same command in fish and am having trouble. I am thinking of creating a separate file and run it with bash, but would be nice how to do this in fish. I am getting a `fish: Command substitutions not allowed` error. I can run this

`npm install -g npm@latest && npm install -g neovim bash-language-server vscode-langservers-extracted graphql -language-service-cli solidity-language-server typescript-language-server`, but it is not async. I have a bunch of other commands like this, hence async would be faster

Thanks

Comment: I've answered below, but just a heads-up that some may consider this off-topic since it's more "shell usage" than "programming/shell scripting".  It's a gray area, however.  Since it involved multiple commands via chaining, I'm going to call it a "script".  In general, though, I'd recommend our sister-Stack Exchange-site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for Fish questions like this.

Comment: Will keep that in mind @NotTheDr01ds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place commands in parenthesis in Bash (or any POSIX shell), you are running them in a subshell, with the `&` of course placing the subshell in the background.

Fish doesn't have the exact concept of a subshell, but for your particular example, you can accomplish the same goal by running in a sub-process rather than a subshell.

```
fish -c "npm install -g npm@latest && npm install -g neovim bash-language-server vscode-langservers-extracted graphql -language-service-cli solidity-language-server typescript-language-server" &
```

There are [several differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/432493) (and maybe others) between a subshell and a sub-process like this, but they don't matter for this particular scenario.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess I should have read the docs more. Forking actually might be beneficial with fish because of cd in scripts etc. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, fish uses parentheses for command substitution, not for grouping commands: `set now (date)` -- in sh that's `now=$(date)`